# Javascript regular expression all between <script> tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make a function that gets a string with html code (as a string) including the script tag - for example: "`<div>dkjdg</div><script>blabla</script>fgfgh<span>hey</span>`" and returns all the script inside the script tag including the open and close tags.

I tried this so far:

```
var s;
function(string)
{
    var a = string.toLowerCase().match("/(.*?)<script>(.*?)<//script>(.*?)/");
    s = a[2];
    return a[1]+a[3];
}
```

`s` is containing what is between the script tags and the return is every thing else.

But it is not working...

Comment: What's not working about it?  Is it not returning anything at all, or is it returning the whole string, or is it returning `fgfgh`?

Comment: "s is what between and the return is every thing else." Huh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And what happens if the block looks like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
  alert('hello </script>');
]]></script>
```

Never parse HTML with regular expressions. Instead, you can do something like this (with a little help from jQuery):

```
function GetScript(str) {
  var div = $('<div>'), tmpdiv = $('<div>'), scr, ret = '<script';
  div[0].innerHTML = str;
  scr = div.find('script');

  for ( var i = 0; i < scr[0].attributes.length; i++ ) {
    var attr = scr[0].attributes[i];

    if ( attr.value && attr.value != '' )
      ret += ' ' + attr.name + '="' + 
             tmpdiv.text(attr.value).html().replace(/"/g, '&quot;') +
             '"';
  }

  return ret + '>' + scr.text() + '</script>';
}
```

That will do exactly what you want, doesn't break unless the input is totally screwed and is more or less 100% cross-browser compatible. Note that we don't want to use jQuery's .html() to set the div content, because that will eval() the  blocks!

This:

```
GetScript("<div>dkjdg</div><script type='yadda\"yadda'>blabla</script>fgfgh<span>hey</span>")
```

will return

```
'<script type="yadda&quot;yadda">blabla</script>'
```

Comment: Thanks alot its working but as i said i also need to get the string without the script i found.

Comment: That's even easier. Just do it like this:

    function Getscript(str) {
      var div = $('<div>');
      div[0].innerHTML = str;
      return div.find('script').text();
    }

Comment: No, i want the normal text without the <script>...</script>

Comment: Did you try that out? Because it does return precisely the script's content without the tags. You could modify the last line of the GetScript() function to look like this:

`return [ scr.text(), ret + '>' + scr.text() + '</script>' ];`

That would return a tuple in which the first index would have only the text content and the second one the whole script tag with attributes et al.

Comment: no you didnt understand me, i want the all text - <div>dkjdg</div><script type='yadda\"yadda'>blabla....  without the <script tags and script content.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, you can do it like this: `function RemoveScript(str) { var div = $('<div>'); div[0].innerHTML = str; div.find('script').remove(); return div.html(); }`

Answer (score 1):

You need to

a) give the function a name
b) escape the slash in the script tag
c) escape the slash in the regex
d) remove the quotes from the regexp
e) include the tags in the brackets
f) not use regex to parse html as mentioned elsewhere

this one is better [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/BzkYu/)

```
var str = "<div>dkjdg</div><script>blabla<\/script>fgfgh<span>hey</span>"
var s;
function parseIt(string)
{
    var a = string.toLowerCase().match(/(.*?)(<script>.*?<\/script>)(.*)/);
    s = a[2];
    return a[1]+a[3];
}
var rest = parseIt(str);
document.write("s:<xm"+"p>"+s+"</xmp><hr/>")    
document.write("rest:<xm"+"p>"+rest+"</xmp><hr/>")
```

Answer (score 0):

At very least you're looking for `<//script>`, because you wrote escape wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to have a tag containing it and its sub elements. You should have a code like.

```
var s = "<div>dkjdg</div><script>blabla</script>fgfgh<span>hey</span>";
function getTagContent(string,tag)
{
    var regex = new RegExp("<"+tag+">"+"(.*)"+"<\/"+tag+">");
    return string.match(regex)[0];
}
alert(getTagContent(s,"script"));
```